# convert columns of pyspark data frame to lowercase

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe in pyspark which has columns in uppercase like `ID`, `COMPANY` and so on

I want to make these column names to `id` `company` and so on. Bacially convert all the columns to lowercase or uppercase depending on the requirement.

I want to do in such away that the data types of the columns remain the same.

How can we do that?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Use `columns` field from DataFrame

```
df = // load
for col in df.columns:
    df = df.withColumnRenamed(col, col.lower())
```

Or, as @zero323 suggested:

```
df.toDF(*[c.lower() for c in df.columns])
```

Comment: It would be much cheaper and (arguably more elegant) to `df.toDF(*[c.lower() for c in df.columns])`

Comment: @zero323 - Thanks, I've edited answer. I must learn Python much more ;)

Comment: You can also use a generator comprehension instead of building a list, i.e. do `df.toDF(*(c.lower() for c in df.columns))`

Answer (score 2):

Could also use select with alias (be sure pyspark.sql.functions are imported as "f"):

```
df.select([f.col(col).alias(col.upper()) for col in df.columns])
```

Comment: I like this as its simple

Answer (score 0):

Please try following code, here **df** is your pypsark dataframe (In this case I have created my dataframe by reading from table)

```
df = spark.sql("select * from <your table name >")
new_column_name_list= list(map(lambda x: x.lower(), df.columns))
df = df.toDF(*new_column_name_list)
display(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

To apply any generic function on the spark dataframe columns (uppercase/lowercase) and then rename the column names, can use the quinn library. Please refer example code:

```
import quinn
def lower_case(col):
  return col.lower()

df_ = quinn.with_columns_renamed(lower_case)(df)
```

lower_case is the function name and df is the initial spark dataframe

If you get an error importing quinn library. Use example code below:

```
%pip install quinn
```